# Using the power button to wake MacBook Air 2019 up from a long term sleep

Tags: macbook-pro, catalina, sleep-wake

I have a MacBook Air 2019 running Catalina 10.15.4. Every time, I shut the laptop lid at night and go to bed and wake up the next morning to open up my laptop, expecting the screen to wake immediately, it doesn't. In fact for the last couple of days, I had to hold the power button for a period of time until I see the screen opening up with the apple logo (as seen in the startup).

Essentially, I thought that my mac shuts down every night, but that's not that case at all. After the apple logo and I put in my mac password. I see all my apps and everything working exactly how I left them last night. For example, I was watching a show on Netflix and if my mac really did shut off, I wouldn't have seen all the apps working in the background.

Now this issue, occurs only when my mac is asleep overnight. In the middle of the day when I leave my mac closed, as in the lid closed, and I come back I don't have to press the power button instead all I gotta do is open the lid.

Basically, what I am asking is how can I stop my mac from requiring me to press the power button every time, to wake it up from a long term sleep?

Comment: Is it logging out ? you can see that in (for Mojave at least) sys pref > privacy & security > advanced > log out after some time of inactivity. https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/mac-help/mh40595/10.15/mac/10.15

Comment: yes it is logging out...but it does that anyway after I close and lid and reopen it again. The  problem is holding the power button every time after a full night of sleep and waking up in the morning

Comment: logging out is different than screen lock.

Comment: Long term sleep is *hibernation.*. What's your battery charge looking like?  Is it plugged in?

Comment: @Allan battery charge is fine and it's not plugged in.